# Get latest MongoDB record by field of datetime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    'datetime': some-date,
    'lat': '32.00',
    'lon': '74.00'
},
{
    'datetime': some-date,
    'lat': '32.00',
    'lon': '74.00'
}
```

How can I get the latest record from MongoDB, where the datetime is the latest one? I want only a single record.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use [`sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and [`limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/):

```
db.col.find().sort({"datetime": -1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: `await db.col.find().sort({"datetime": -1}).limit(1).next()` to return object instead of mongo cursor

Answer (score 13):

For `node.js` you can use the `findOne()` function:

```
db.collection('yourCollectionName').findOne(
  {},
  { sort: { datetime: -1 } },
  (err, data) => {
     console.log(data);
  },
);
```

Comment: This solution yields the greatest performance in my experiences.

Comment: Just doesn't work for me. Any other conditions need to apply, such as the format the date is saved in? I have ISODate

Comment: This is really useful if you want to build your sort conditionally! Such as based on whether any options are specified, you also attach options to the query and if you don't have any specified options, the query will not contain any. 

Whereas the accepted answer would always contain the .sort() and also given the vast amount of options one can specify (for example in MongoDB 3.6: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find), it may quickly become more practical to specify it through the options object, like here, rather than individual function at a time.